# carouFredSel slideTo/slideToPage events

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

I'm having a bit of trouble with using carouFredSel as an infinite circular slider with controls to go to specific slides. Here is my implementation code:

```
$('.circular-gallery ul').carouFredSel({
    width: '100%',
    height:270,
    align:'center',
    items: {
        start: 10,
        width:340,
        visible: 10
    },
    prev: {
        button: $('.circular-gallery .prev')
    },
    next: {
        button: $('.circular-gallery .next')
    },
    scroll: {
        items: 1,
        easing: 'quadratic',
        onBefore: function(data){
            var $current = $(data.items.visible[4]);
            if(!data.scroll.duration){ // this happens on init, so just set active class
                $current.addClass('active');
            } else {
                var $active = $('.circular-gallery ul li.active');
                $active.find('.physician-name').fadeOut('normal', function(){
                    $(this).css('display','block').css('visibility','hidden');
                    $active.removeClass('active');
                });
                $current.find('.physician-name').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('normal', function(){
                    $current.addClass('active');
                });
            }
        }
    },
    auto: {
        play: false
    }
});

var $items = {};
$('.physician').hoverIntent(function(){
    slideToPhysician($(this).attr('rel'));
}, function(){ return false; });

function slideToPhysician(rel){
    var $items = $('.circular-gallery ul li').trigger('currentVisible');
    var index = $items.index($('li.'+rel));
    //console.log(index);
    //$('.circular-gallery ul').trigger('slideToPage', index);
    $('.circular-gallery ul').trigger('slideTo', index);
}
```

The problem is the index for each element is not constant. It changes each time the slider moves. So I'm having trouble determining which one to slide to. I have classes on each li in my slider and am using the "rel" attribute on my links to pass the corresponding class to the hoverIntent event. During debugging, if I rollover the same name, I might get the index of 6, then it slides to some slide, and if I rollover it again, i get 10. I can't figure out the pattern or if I'm doing something wrong in the first place.

Maybe I have just done something incorrectly, but the goal is to have a slider with the "highlighted" item in the center of the page, then if you hover over a name for a few seconds, the slider moves to that specific photo.

Thanks for taking your time to help!

Comment: Ok, so what I ended up doing is using slideTo instead of slideToPage, then passing the jQuery object instead of the index. That got it sliding to a consistently wrong item. Then I added a deviation of 11. Not sure why 11, but I'm hoping it has nothing to do with the # of elements in there. I expect this to break if they add/remove one. I really don't have an explanation as to how to ensure this is correct, but maybe someone else can shed some light on it.

Answer (score 5):

I solved nearly the same problem with passing an array as parameter to `slideTo` Event. It contains the clicked item and the carouFredSel Item index:

```
$li.on('click', function() {
  var index = 0;
  $('#fred').trigger('slideTo', [$(this), index]);
});
```

Check the examples [here](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel)

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me:

```
$('.circular-gallery ul li')('click', function() {
  $('#fred').trigger('slideTo', $(this).index());
});
```