# carousel only display visible items

Tags: jquery, drupal, caroufredsel

I would like to target only visible items in the caroufredsel carousel and have non-visible items set to display: none; to minimize page load times.

I have seen several posts regarding this but have not found anything that works. Anybody able to help me out?

Note - I am implementing in Drupal so I'm using `jQuery` in place of `$`.

HTML:

```
<div class="homepageHeroCarousel"><!-- class of slide for animation -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="sites/all/themes/visit_mendocino/assets/images/hero01.jpg" width="2000" height="900" alt="" />
          <div class="container">
            <div class="caption">
              <h2><a href="#">Scenic Drive on Highway 1</a></h2>
              <p>Getting here is only part<br/>of the experience.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="7">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div><!-- end caption -->
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="sites/all/themes/visit_mendocino/assets/images/hero02.jpg" width="2000" height="900" alt="" />
          <div class="container">
            <div class="caption">
              <h2><a href="#">Fern Canyon Waterfall</a></h2>
              <p>Meander through lush ground and connect with the sounds of the forest.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="8">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div><!-- end caption -->
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="prev" id="home_prev" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x">&#8203;</i></a>
  <a class="next" id="home_next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x">&#8203;</i></a>
  <!-- <div class="controls"></div> -->
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  var carousel = jQuery(".homepageHeroCarousel .carousel-inner ul");
  carousel.carouFredSel({
    circular: true,
    infinite: false,
    responsive: true,
    items: {
      visible: 1,
      minimum: 1,
      width: 1170
    },
    scroll: {
      fx: "scroll",
      easing: "linear",
      duration: 1000,
      onAfter: function() {
        var vis = jQuery(".homepageHeroCarousel .carousel-inner ul").triggerHandler("currentVisible");       //get all visible items
        jQuery(".homepageHeroCarousel .carousel-inner ul").children().removeClass("active");                 // remove all .active classes
        vis.filter(":eq(1)").addClass("active");
      }
    },
    auto: false,
    prev : "#home_prev",
    next : "#home_next",
    //pagination: ".homepageHeroCarousel  .controls",
    onCreate: function () {
      jQuery(window).on('resize', function () {
        carousel.parent().add(carousel).height(carousel.children().first().height());
      }).trigger('resize');
      var vis = jQuery(".homepageHeroCarousel .carousel-inner ul").triggerHandler("currentVisible");       //get all visible items
      jQuery(".homepageHeroCarousel .carousel-inner ul").children().removeClass("active");                 // remove all .active classes
      vis.filter(":eq(1)").addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
     jQuery(".homepageHeroCarousel .carousel-inner ul").swiperight(function() {  
        jQuery('#home_prev').click();  
        });  
     jQuery(".homepageHeroCarousel .carousel-inner ul").swipeleft(function() {  
        jQuery('#home_next').click();
   });  
});
```

Comment: Setting items to `display: none;` won't reduce page load times.

Comment: Given that (as @DrCord stated) setting items to `display:none;` won't reduce load times, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is Lazy Load the images right? Or have the images not take up so much space or load time? If that is it, I am trying to accomplish the same thing. I found many methods to Lazy Load the next image.

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/14/

I tried this example, but it doesn't seem to work well if you press the previous button. It also just is sort of glitchy altogether. Even on just 1 slider, it doesn't work on the next button all the time. 1/10 chance or so that the lazy load fails and the placeholder image still shows. Maybe less. But still sometimes it fails. Previous almost always fails. Multiple sliders require a change in the function or multiples of the same function with differently named variables. Also, only works on single sliders. I find it isn't working when multiple items are visible. I have a responsive site with max 3 visible and minimum 1 visible, so it changes from 3 to 2 to 1 item, depending on screen size. I have scroll set to 1 item, so 3 are visible, and it scrolls, circular, 1 at a time. The preload never works, rather, it tries to work on the second scroll click, and grabs the wrong images, because the variable for the lazy load function remains an old value.

[carouFredSel slideTo/slideToPage events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417011/caroufredsel-slideto-slidetopage-events)

This was an attempt to add active class to use to find the correct indexes to lazy load the correct images and get the correct image sources per slide etc. It isn't working for me for multiple visible items either.

[carouFredSel add class to active slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614266/caroufredsel-add-class-to-active-slide)

I didn't get this to work either. Overall, I think the idea is to always actually load the first image, without lazy load, or whatever visible items should be there on load. Then, you could either also include the next and previous slides, OR lazy load them shortly after the page loads, it makes little difference - either way on load the next and previous slides need to be made ready.

Then, each time the slider slides to the next or previous slides, you need to use javascript (during onAfter or onBefore events for CarouFredsel) to yet again lazy load the next and previous slides, respective to the new current slide. I am not 100% sure how this can be done, and am working on it myself, but likely "active" class should be added to all visible items (even in the case of variable visible items (min and max)) and then JS should be used to check the indexes of the items with active class, and lazy load the item with 1 higher index then the last item with active, and lazy load the item with 1 lower index then the first item with active.

I will write back when I have an answer, but if anyone is to read this today or tomorrow and get the answer, please let us in. ALSO, please be sure to include the hieght adjustments from samhdir's original question. It appears to fix the height of the slider container to equal the first slide (hopefully he also couples this with a script that makes all slides equal to the tallest slide). I also will need this. My development site: uo-new.unaomnia.com and my main site: unaomnia.com